# Store first few elements in array in another array if they exist

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array that contains any number of objects, how could you cleanly and safely get the first 3 elements out of it to store in a new array? If the array does not contain at least 3 elements, it should not trigger a runtime exception, instead it should only add the number of elements in the array to the new array.

I thought this might work, but it won't compile in Xcode 7, and if it did I don't imagine it would behave safely as I desire:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arr2 = arr1[0..<3]
//Expected: arr == [1, 2, 3]

let arr1 = [1, 2]
let arr2 = arr1[0..<3]
//Expected: arr2 == [1, 2]

let arr1 = [Int]()
let arr2 = arr1[0..<3]
//Expected: arr2 == []
```

Of course one could always do something like this, or you could use a for loop, but neither is clean and concise. I want a to find a swiftier way.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2]
var arr2 = [Int]()
if photos.count > 0 {
    arr2.append(arr1[0])
}
if photos.count > 1 {
    arr2.append(arr1[1])
}
if photos.count > 2 {
    arr2.append(arr1[2])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be

```
let arr2 = arr1.prefix(3)
```

Comment: What about ranges like `3..<6`?

Comment: @AaronBrager The original question is about first three.

Comment: Perfect for what I need, just beautiful

Answer (score 0):

You can implement what you want with an extension to `Array`:

```
extension Array {
    func safeRange(range : Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        guard range.startIndex >= 0 && range.endIndex >= 0 else {
            fatalError("Ranges with negative numbers aren't supported")
        }

        var shrinkingRange = range

        while shrinkingRange.endIndex > shrinkingRange.startIndex + 1 {
            if shrinkingRange.endIndex <= self.count {
                return self[shrinkingRange]
            }

            shrinkingRange.endIndex = shrinkingRange.endIndex - 1
        }

        return []
    }
}
```

The examples you gave behave as expected:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arr2 = arr1.safeRange(0..<3)
//Expected: arr == [1, 2, 3]

let arr3 = [1, 2]
let arr4 = arr3.safeRange(0..<3)
//Expected: arr2 == [1, 2]

let arr5 = [Int]()
let arr6 = arr5.safeRange(0..<3)
//Expected: arr2 == []
```

You could also use `filter`:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable, Index == Int {
    func safeRange(range : Range<Int>) -> [Self.Generator.Element] {
        return self.filter {
            let index = self.indexOf($0)!
            return index >= range.startIndex && index < range.endIndex
        }
    }
}
```

(This may fail if your array contains duplicate elements, since `indexOf` returns the index of the first instance.)

Comment: This would be a neat extension to have around! Overkill for my specific needs, but very useful for others I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a function…

```
import Swift

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let arr2 = [1, 2]
let arr3 = [Int]()

func firstThree(data: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var results = [Int]()
    for (index, number) in data.enumerate() {
        if (index < 3) {
            results.append(number)
        }
    }
   return results
}

print(firstThree(arr1))
print(firstThree(arr2))
print(firstThree(arr3))
```

This prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[]
```

A slightly better approach would be to use generics and get an N number of items:

```
func genericFirstItems<T>(array: [T], numberOfItems: Int) -> [T] {
    var results = [T]()

    for (index, item) in array.enumerate() {
        if index < numberOfItems {
            results.append(item)
        }
    }
    return results
}

print(genericFirstItems(arr1, numberOfItems: 3))
print(genericFirstItems(arr2, numberOfItems: 3))
print(genericFirstItems(arr3, numberOfItems: 3))
```

This has the same output.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[]
```